# mysql-connector-python is not supported in python3.2?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I've tried installing mysql-connector python using

`pip install mysql-connector-python`

and

`pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python`

I get the following error saying python v3.2 is not supported.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/wolfgang/projects/python/python_backend/build/mysql-connector-python/setup.py", line 41, in <module>
        import setupinfo
      File "setupinfo.py", line 37, in <module>
        major=sys.version_info[0], minor=sys.version_info[1]
    RuntimeError: Python v3.2 is not supported
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/wolfgang/projects/python/python_backend/build/mysql-connector-python/setup.py", line 41, in <module>

    import setupinfo

  File "setupinfo.py", line 37, in <module>

    major=sys.version_info[0], minor=sys.version_info[1]

RuntimeError: Python v3.2 is not supported

----------------------------------------
```

Should i upgrade my python version? or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some important improvement in 2.x compatibility in Python 3.3, so a lot of packages only support 3.3+. mysql-connector-python is one of them.  You are unlikely to be able to fix it without a large amount of work.  It would be much easier to just install a later version.